Codeigniter 3: How to show camera permission when accessing android webview
I'm developing a web application using Codeigniter 3 that needs to take photo of user when signing up.
Everything works very well on desktop browser (Chrome), it could show permission to access webcam but when i try to access on Android web view (Chrome too), nothing shows
i have included
navigator.permissions.query({name: 'camera'})
    .then((permissionObj) => {
     console.log(permissionObj.state);
    })

and
RequestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA), REQUEST_CODE)

too but still not a single permission is appearing on android chrome.
is there anyone who facing the same problem or someone who have the solution to solve my problem?
